# How to get and set names in an array of objects?

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, getter-setter

I have a homework assignment but I'm very new to Java and have been trying for the past two days to create an array of player objects, set the names and get the names.

But whatever I try I get errors. I've watched lots of tutorials and copied out exactly what they've done but it doesn't work. How do I correctly create the array and get/set the names?

I have a Game class and a Player class:

Game class -- one version:

```
Player[] players = new Player[3];

//All the tutorials I've seen show both these types of putting names in:

players[0] = new Player(); 

//followed by:
players[0].setName("name");
//or...

players[0] = new Player("human"); 

 //my errors on both: unknown class 'players'... 
//unexpected token... invalid method... etc etc
```

Gmae class - different version (using a method):

```
//for the homework, I'm expected to put it all into a method
//ideally I'd be using the setName method from the Players class (below)
//but that doesn't work here

void createPlayers(Player[] players) { 
    for (Player p : players) {
        players[0] = new Player("human");
        players[1] = new Player("Greg");
        players[2] = new Player("Susan");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
Game obj = new Game();

//I had to change Players[] to static to get a printout but it's not supposed 
//to be static

 //I tried these separately to check output
//I need to be able to get the name of a player

    obj.createPlayers(players); //no output 

    for (Player pl : players) {
        System.out.println("Name = " + pl); //null null null
    }
    System.out.println(obj.players[0]); //null
    obj.player[0].getName(); //cannot resolve symbol 'player'
}
```

Game Class -- another version (putting everything in main):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Main game = new Main();

    Player p0 = new Player("Jeff"); //it errored if I didn't put a name
    Player p1 = new Player("Susan"); //but I need to be able to change names
    Player p2 = new Player("Michael");

    Player[] players = new Player[3];
    players[0] = p0;
    players[1] = p1;
    players[2] = p2;

    p2.setPName("Alan");
    System.out.println(p2.getPName()); //output: null
```

Player class: features getters and setters which I would ideally be using to get and set the player names but I don't know how to make them work in my Game class.

```
private String name;

Player (String name) { this.name = name; }

public void setName(String name) { this.name = name;  }

public String getName() { return name; }
```

Comment: where is version you actually work with? and place full erro stacktrace

Comment: why is the setter defined with name `setName` but called `setPName`. Looks like you mixed up code from several tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple modification on your Game class gave me this, which pretty much does what you want to do:

```
public class Game {

        void createPlayers(Player[] players) {
            Player player1 = new Player();
            player1.setName("human");

            Player player2 = new Player();
            player2.setName("Greg");

            Player player3 = new Player();
            player3.setName("Susan");

            players[0] = player1;
            players[1] = player2;
            players[2] = player3;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Player[] players = new Player[3];

            Game obj = new Game();
            obj.createPlayers(players);

            for (Player pl : players) {
                System.out.println("Name = " + pl.getName());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Fantastic! This is very clear and easy for me to follow, and it works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

1) For your game class -- one version

```
players[0] = new Player();
```

will not work as you dont have any defautl constructor in your class Player.
You can add default constructor and your class will look like this.

```
private String name;

Player () {}

Player (String name) { this.name = name; }

public void setName(String name) { this.name = name;  }

public String getName() { return name; }
```

2) For your game class --different version
     In your main class you have not created the list of players and without creating list you are passing it in the method.

in your main class before

```
obj.createPlayers(players);
```

add `Player[] players = new Player[3];`

3) For your Game Class -- another version
    the output is null because `System.out.println(p2.getPName());` you are trying to do `p2.getPName()` but in your class Player the getter is `getName()`. Just change to it, it will work.

Comment: Thank you for the advice about the default constructor, I hadn't realized I was missing that.

Answer (score 1):

In first listing where you create new Player without name it's wrong because after you defined new constructor in class with argument default constructor disabled, you need to either to add default constructor or create players with names.

> `Player[] players = new Player[3];`
>
> //All the tutorials I've seen show both these types of putting names
>   in:
>
> `players[0] = new Player();`<-- wrong! because you don't have this`
>   constructor in Player class

Another parts of your code also contains errors, you place one getters and setters method names in Player class but trying to use them with another names.

```
class Player {
  private String name;

  Player (String name) { this.name = name; }

  public void setName(String name) { this.name = name;  }

  public String getName() { return name; }
}
```

> ```
>     p2.setPName("Alan");
>     System.out.println(p2.getPName()); <--this method is not exists
> ```

Correct code will be like that, but pay attention it's bad design:

```
public class Main {

        public static void main(String...args) {
            Game game = new Game();
            Player[] players = game.getPlayers();
            for(Player player : players) {
                System.out.println(player.getName());
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
                players[i].setName("new name");
            }
            for(Player player : players) {
                System.out.println(player.getName());
            }
        }

}

class Player {
    private String name;

    public Player(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public String getName() { return name; }
}

class Game {
    private Player[] players;

    public Game() {
        players = { new Player("human"), new Player("Greg"), new Player("Susan") };
    }

   public Player[] getPlayers() {
        return players;
   }
}
```

place this code in file with *Main.java* name and in the same folder put in console 
*javac Main.java* after that launch your program with *java Main* command

output will be:

```
human
Greg
Susan
new name
new name
new name
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. I understand this a bit better now.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Player Class  . Create a package named test and create a class

package test;

public class Player {
private String name;

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

}

 //Create a Game class in same package 

 package test;

 public class Game {
 //Game Name is just name of the game
 private String gameName;
 private Player[] players;
 public String getGameName() {
 return gameName;
 }
 public void setGameName(String gameName) {
 this.gameName = gameName;
 }
 public Player[] getPlayers() {
 return players;
 }
 public void setPlayers(Player[] players) {
 this.players = players;
 }

 }

 //Create a Test class in same package which contains main method 

  package test;

  public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  Game game =new Game();

  Player []players = new Player[3];

  players[0]= new Player(); //Create Player Object and assign it into 
  player[0]
  players[0].setName("name1");

  players[1] = new Player();
  players[1].setName("name2");

  players[2] = new Player();
  players[2].setName("name3");

  game.setPlayers(players);

  for(Player player : game.getPlayers()){
    System.out.println(player.getName());
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It looks like you don't have a default constructor. So you need to pass name to the constructor. This is cause of undefined method error you got for first try.
2. For the second the players are not declared in local scope. Just declare Player[] in main method and you will be fine.
3. Third looks fine, except the method getPName is not defined or its value is null. Since this part of code you have not provided, I can't comment further on this.